# QML import statement: why specify module version?

Tags: qt, import, module, qml, versioning

I know what version of Qt I'm shipping my app with. And I suppose a single version of Qt contains only a single version of each QML module. So if I were to write:

```
import QtQuick
```

(no version specified), that would be unambiguous. So why is it necessary to specify the module version?

Comment: Any light here ?

Answer (score 2):

It is, so everyone can see, which version is demanded.

It might be that you ship your code, using features of QtQuick 2.7, someone
tries to open it with an older version (say: QtQuick 2.5) and strangely - it's broken.
If you import a specific version, it is clear, that the error stems from an too old version.

I think it is the best to always try to use the least version. So unless you use features of QtQuick 2.7, declare the older ones, to maximize compatibility.

Comment: When I ship my QML code, it will only be loaded by *my* app, using the Qt libraries *I* shipped, so I have full control over the version with which the QML code will be loaded.

Comment: Lots of QML Projects are released under licenses, that might allow the reuse and or alternation of the code.